# Programmatically clicking the Quora "more" button

Tags: javascript, ruby, ajax, dom, web

I'm trying to use watir to programmatically click the "more" button at the bottom of a page like http://www.quora.com/Startups/best_questions. I currently have code that looks like:

```
    require 'watir-webdriver'
    b = Watir::Browser.new
    b.goto 'quora.com/'+ ARGV[2] + '/best_questions'

    show_more = b.button(:id => "more_button")
    show_more.click
```

But I'm having some trouble finding the id of the button in DOM. I'm actually not even sure that this is the correct approach.

Answer (score 1):

From chrome or firefox (with firebug) right click on the button and go to inspect element.
In the inspector panel you can see that it's actually a div and it looks like this:

```
<div class="pager_next action_button row" id="__w2_pxNLyPP_more">More</div>
```

so you would do:

```
b.div(:text => 'More').click
```

or

```
b.div(:class => 'pager_next').click
```